# Generic Request with object receives values as Double instead of Integer

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm having some troubles with my Spring Restful Service. My request has a generic Object called "value".

`Object value;`

When I do a POST request to my Service, with the following body:

```
{
  "value" : [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

At some point, when I get those values in my Request object, they turn to Doubles

```
{
  "value" : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
}
```

Does any one have an idea of what could be happening there?
If you need more info just let me know. That is basically what I'm doing, receiving numbers with the wrong type.

Thanks!

Edit: It was because G-Son was enabled instead of jackson

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: It is always advisable to use a specific model for each request rather than having a generic `Object` as the request model in any enterprise application(not only this, if you are just started learning, then start following this, as this will help you in future). If you do so, you can declare the `value` as `integer array/list.`

Answer (score 0):

I was using gson, changed json strategy to jackson and everything works fine now!